# Apache tika architecture & processing nodes

Tags: apache, apache-tika

I have just started exploring Apache Tika.
I want to check how apache tika back ground processes work.

I tried executing Tika in a standalone machine but wanted to know how it works in Cloudera Cluster real time environment.

Example: I have a 200 page pdf content and use Tika to extract the text or features. Will Tika execute this process using a single node (i.e considering one file as one block) or will it execute using multiple nodes?

Im just comparing Tika process to Mapreduce and learn if Tika is also processing a file block by block.

Please help me to understand this background processes.

I don't have the code with me now.

Please help me to understand this background processes work in terms of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check how apache tika back ground processes work.

Apache Tika uses an abstraction [TikaInputStream](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/io/TikaInputStream.java) on the top of Java's [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) class. Which means in reads the files as stream of bytes. No blocks, nothing fancy at low level!

> I tried executing Tika in a standalone machine but wanted to know how it works in Cloudera Cluster real time environment.
>
> Example: I have a 200 page pdf content and use Tika to extract the
>   text or features. Will Tika execute this process using a single node
>   (i.e considering one file as one block) or will it execute using
>   multiple nodes?
>
> Im just comparing Tika process to Mapreduce and learn if Tika is also
>   processing a file block by block.

Since you mentioned Map-Reduce specifically, the behavior of using Apache Tika on CDH cluster can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-mapreduce-biginsights-analysis/). Basically, on CDH, your MR app will read the files from HDFS (using blocks methodology) and process the split using the Apache Tika libraries just like you are doing on standalone basis. Note that processing will be splitted based on Input Splits(Underlying HDFS blocks). A working example can be found here :
https://github.com/ppruski/tika-hadoop-mapreduce

So you can definitely use CDH cluster to achive the efficiency of parallel processing as MR or Spark both uses same methodology to calculate input splits.